# commparing string with multiple enum string

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum like following

```
public enum CommonEnum
{
    l, el, ad, an, ar, ash, at, az,Abu
}
```

then i need to check that enum with string. like following.

```
else if (SplitName[1].Contains(Common.CommonEnum.ad.ToString()))
{                   
}
```

if i need to check that string  with all enum values means what i want to do?

i tried  following thing

```
else if (SplitName[1].Contains(Common.CommonEnum.ad.ToString())|| SplitName[1].Contains(Common.CommonEnum.abu.ToString()))
{

}
```

Is there any other technique?

Comment: what would be the value of `SplitName[1]`, any samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CommonEnum), SplitName[1]))
```

[Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GNJZEa)

Answer (score 1):

To check contains you can try something like the following:

```
string SplitName = "sujith";
var resultBool = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CommonEnum)).Any(x => SplitName.Contains(x));
// will give you false 
// gives you true if SplitName = "elsujith"
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eJYi8v)